# Как выставить чистый белый фон приложения в KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy

Я так понял нужно использовать Theming, но не видел где можно задать свой цвет

Comment: а штука от обычного киви не подойдёт ? from kivy.core.window import Window  # 
Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1, 0)

Comment: @Интик не, это игноририуется в MDApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У виджетов KivyMD есть параметр `md_bg_color`- https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/components/boxlayout/index.html#mdboxlayout Ну, и инструкции `Canvas` никто не отмел пока.